# Double slit experiment - Is there a 1/2^n chance for an unobserved single particle to create non interference pattern? n is the number of shots made

Tags: quantum-mechanics

While shooting the electrons individually, considering the probability to be 50/50 for each firing, there would be a single chance that all the electrons fall onto a single point. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: If not, then the succeeding electron should have knowledge of the decision taken by previous electrons while colliding on the screen. isn't it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DjvO0P5-SMxk&ved=2ahUKEwjY1sOWuKrfAhVKhqYKHZ5IB4UQwqsBMAF6BAgMEAU&usg=AOvVaw22vkxL0FdYXBNJgAzoNOZl single electrons lead to an interference pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is different. I agree that interference patterns do form in a double slit experiment. But if we consider the 0.5 probability for each passing electron there would be one single scenario in which all the electrons pass through same slit. Is this observed? For e.g if 7 electrons are shot, there is a 1/128th chance for all of them to pass through the same slit.

Comment: There is no such thing as "passing through a single slit" because no interference would occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interference pattern is the average for a large number of particles, in other words the probability distribution . For a finite number the observed pattern is a statistical variation about this average. The size of the fluctuation diminishes, I am guessing now, as $1/\sqrt{n}$. So there is a chance that all electrons land on the same spot, and there is a chance that the detected patter does not look like an interference pattern. This chance rapidly decreases with the number of detected particles, so there is no chance of a  "non interference" pattern.